# Disabling video autoplay in Edge and disabling download in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, microsoft-edge

Client wants to have videos without autoplay disabled and although i made the changes, we are having issues with it on Edge and IE.

- In Edge the video autoplay
- In Internet Explorer it prompts to download the mp4 file but even disabling downloading the video in the settings, nothing shows up where the video should be.

I've changed my code to force disabling of autoplay but that only works fine in Firefox and Chrome

The JQuery:

```
obj_adjustments.removeAutoplay = function() {
    var $iframe = $("iframe");        

    $iframe.on("load", function () {
        var $iframeContents = $iframe.contents();

        $iframeContents.find("video").removeAttr("autoplay");  
    });      
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="720" scrolling="no" 
    src="Video.mp4" 
    width="1280" style="height: 832px;">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <video 
        controls="" name="media"><source src="Video.mp4" 
        type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

For IE - Force disabling of download/Force video to play

For Edge - Disable autoplay

Comment: for Edge - does you <video> tag have the autoplay attribute? Simpler to just remove it. For IE, does the video itself play in the browser if you just link to it directly?

Comment: In Edge there isn't the autoplay. In IE it always prompts to download.

Comment: can we see your HTML for the video tag. Does your server have the correct mime type for the mp4 video (so IE knows to play it rather than download). Edge won't autoplay unless you're doing something to request that

Comment: @Fab, I again made a test with MS Edge and IE. I find that code is working fine with IE and it does not download the video. In MS Edge, I am able to produce the issue. I find that even if I remove the autoplay attribute, Edge is playing the video. I had provided the feedback regarding this issue to MS Edge developers. Thanks for your understanding.